# iOS 8 setting setSeparatorInset to Zero

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to set my TableView Cell inset to UIEdgeInsetsZero but it has zero effect on my table view.

I am getting this issue with new iOS 8 Betas. Beta 5 seems to have this issue as well. Is this a legit issue, or am I doing something wrong?

```
 self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

Answer (score 21):

This seems to be an issue in the iOS8 betas:

Workaround:
Set the layoutMargins property of the cells and the UITableView to UIEdgeInsetsZero.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [...]

    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    return cell;
}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [...]

    self.myTableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Comment: Getting same problem in iOS7 with xcode6 beta6 and this doesn't fix it.

Comment: layoutMargins is available in ios8 only

Comment: if want to support both iO7 and iOS8 preffix the layoutMargins call with if([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    self.myTableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

Comment: This doesn't work well if you only want to set the edge insets for a particular cell and not the entire tableView though. Is there still a way to accomplish that?